# Does Switch Button in Android support toggling images?

Tags: android, togglebutton

I am trying to put ON/OFF toggle images for Switch Button. But it doesn't reflect. Does the Switch button provide feature to add two selector images?

Below is my code :

```
<Switch
            android:id="@+id/switchbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/bgtoggle"
            android:checked="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:ignore="NewApi" />
```

res/drawable/bgtoggle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_off" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_off"></item>
</selector>
```